# Como puedo alinear dos <p> dentro de un <td>

Tags: html, html-tabla, outlook

Estoy haciendo una firma para Outlook usando una tabla HTML, la cuestion es que estoy tratando de posicionar dos `<p>` dentro de un `<td>` y que queden alineados.

Probé usando un `display:flex` pero Outlook no me reconoce esa propiedad.

**¿Ideas para solucionarlo? ¿Que otra propiedad debería usar?**

Dejo abajo el código actual por las dudas, los `<td>` en cuestión tienen una `class="nomYdir"` para identificarlos mas rápido:

```
 <table cellspacing="0"
    style="max-width: 600px;  margin: 0 auto; font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #001c4c; text-align: center; width: 600px; height: 100px;">
            <img style="height: 100px;" src="https://i.postimg.cc/5yJt5Pp6/membrete-sin-balnco.jpg" alt="loguito">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #f7f7f7;">
            <div style="text-align: justify;">


                <p style="font-size: 15px; margin: 2px;">Hola como estas</p>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nomYdir" style="height: 51px; color: #f7f7f7; background-color: #001c4c;">
            <p style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 6px; font-size: 20px; width: 50%;">Dr. Atilio
                Silvio Maculus</p>
            <p style="margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 6px; text-align: right; width: 50%;">+54
                1141192
                <br>maculus@gmail.com
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="margin-top: 0px;">
        <td style="background-color: #001c4c; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
            <hr style="color: #f7f7f7;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nomYdir" style="height: 90px;  color: #f7f7f7; background-color: #001c4c;">
            <p
                style=" text-align: left; width: 49%; border-right: solid 2px #f7f7f7; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 6px; font-size: 12px;">
                Parana
                600
                3° Piso Of. 8 <br>
                C.A.B.A (1017) <br>
                Tel/Fax: 4373-6340/6418 - 4375-5499</p>
            <p style="text-align: right; width: 49%; margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 6px; font-size: 12px;">
                Panamericana Ramal Pilar Km
                50.5 <br>
                1er Piso Of.1008. <br> Pilar, Bs.As (1629) <br>
                Tel: 0230-437456
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 90px; display: block; background-color: #f7f7f7;">
            <p
                style="text-align: center; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-size: 10px; color: #001c4c;">
                Este E-mail es
                confidencial y
                puede tener informacion amparada por el
                secreto profesional. No debera
                copiar o divulgar su contenido a ninguna persona. Si usted ha recibido este E-,ail por error,
                porfavor informenoslo por este medio y eliminelo de su sistema. Muchas gracias.</p>

            <p
                style="text-align: center; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-size: 10px;  color: #001c4c; ">
                This message is
                confidential and
                contains priviliged information legalle exempt from disclosure. You should not copy this message or
                disclose it to anyone. If you have recieved it by mistake please let us know by e-mail immeadiately
                and delete it from your computer. Thank you very much. </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

He modificado tú código.

Verifiquemos si ese es el resultado que necesitas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table cellspacing="0"
    style="max-width: 600px;  margin: 0 auto; font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #001c4c; text-align: center; width: 600px; height: 100px;">
            <img style="height: 100px;" src="https://i.postimg.cc/5yJt5Pp6/membrete-sin-balnco.jpg" alt="loguito">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #f7f7f7;">
            <div style="text-align: justify;">


                <p style="font-size: 15px; margin: 2px;">Hola como estas</p>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nomYdir" style="height: 51px; color: #f7f7f7; background-color: #001c4c;">
            <p style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 6px; font-size: 20px; width: 50%;">Dr. Atilio
                Silvio Maculus</p>
            <p style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 6px; text-align: left; width: 50%;">+54
                1141192
                <br>maculus@gmail.com
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="margin-top: 0px;">
        <td style="background-color: #001c4c; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
            <hr style="color: #f7f7f7;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nomYdir" style="text-align: left;height: 90px;  color: #f7f7f7; background-color: #001c4c;">
            <p
                style=" text-align: left; width: 49%; border-right: solid 2px #f7f7f7; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 6px; font-size: 12px;">
                Parana
                600
                3° Piso Of. 8 <br>
                C.A.B.A (1017) <br>
                Tel/Fax: 4373-6340/6418 - 4375-5499</p>
            <p style="text-align: right; width: 49%; margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 6px; font-size: 12px;">
                Panamericana Ramal Pilar Km
                50.5 <br>
                1er Piso Of.1008. <br> Pilar, Bs.As (1629) <br>
                Tel: 0230-437456
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 90px; display: block; background-color: #f7f7f7;">
            <p
                style="text-align: center; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-size: 10px; color: #001c4c;">
                Este E-mail es
                confidencial y
                puede tener informacion amparada por el
                secreto profesional. No debera
                copiar o divulgar su contenido a ninguna persona. Si usted ha recibido este E-,ail por error,
                porfavor informenoslo por este medio y eliminelo de su sistema. Muchas gracias.</p>

            <p
                style="text-align: center; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-size: 10px;  color: #001c4c; ">
                This message is
                confidential and
                contains priviliged information legalle exempt from disclosure. You should not copy this message or
                disclose it to anyone. If you have recieved it by mistake please let us know by e-mail immeadiately
                and delete it from your computer. Thank you very much. </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como estas? Perdon la demora en la respuesta. No pude solucionarlo con tu codigo, muchas gracias por el aporte igual. Saludos.